# Why is this my default path?

Tags: terminal, path

[image: screenshot]
For some reason I get this crazy path with a ton of shims and what not and I'm wondering... why? This is the default path when I open terminal. If I change it what will I break, and how to I get it back to a more normal path? Any information would be great.

Answer (score 0):

PATH is basically just an environment variable in UNIX systems. It's basic function is to define where to search for executable files.
Yes, you can change it by adding directories or removing them.

The very simple and default output is something like this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
```